Length of a swirl on a cone
I have a simple $3$-dimensional arc length problem that surprisingly is not easily available on the Internet. "Assume that we have a cone of height $h$ and diameter $D$, and assume that its axis of symmetry is along the $z$-axis. It is to be striped so that the distance between consecutive points of intersection between a plane through the axis of the cone and the cone is $x$.
I want to calculate the length of the thread.
According to MathWorld, if $a$ is the angular frequency, the length is
$$s(h) = \frac{1}{2} \, h \sqrt{1 + r^2(1 + a^2 h^2) \ } 
+ \frac{1 + r^2}{2ar} \sinh^{-1} \left(\frac{arh}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}}\right).$$
My concern is about "$a$." I do not understand the physical interpretation of "angular frequency" in this scenario. If the thread starts at the tip of the cone along the $xz$-plane, what would be the physical interpretation of $a=3$?
If I want the distance between threads to be $x$, how do I adjust the formula provided by Mathworld to replace $a$ with $x$?
